# Error AMQ4036 when trying to add a QueueManager to a Cluster in IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to setup a MQ Cluster that has the following config

1. There are 3 host machines, ubuntuvm-1, ubuntuvm-2 and ubuntuvm-3
2. ubuntuvm-1 has one Full repository queue manager and one partial repository queue manager. QM_FR1, QM_PR1
3. ubuntuvm-2 is same as above. QM_FR2, QM_PR2
4. ubuntuvm-3 has only one partial repository queue manager, QM_PR3

Following are the steps I have taken

1. I have created cluster receiver channels on each queue manager that point to its own queue manager.
2. I have created cluster sender channels that point to at least one full repository.
   I have made sure that the channels are correct, i see the tests pass when I run them through the MQ Explorer.

I get an error when using MQ Explorer, I try to add the QM_FR1 queue manger to cluster (CLUSTER1).
Following is the error.

```
Access not permitted. You are not authorized to perform this operation. (AMQ4036)
Severity: 10 (Warning)
Explanation: The queue manager security mechanism has indicated that the userid associated with this request is not authorized to access the object.
```

**Why am I getting this error and how do I fix this?**

Please shout if you want me to provide more details.

Comment: Are you performing the actions as the 'mom' user? Check your authorization permissions via 'dspmqaut'.

Comment: Check this link for info about setting authorities to administer MQ over explorer:  https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21250706  You could use the MQS_REPORT_NOAUTH or MQSAUTHERRORS setting to get more info about the authority failure.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21299319

Comment: Look in the QM_FR1 AMQERR01.LOG and find the error message(s) that show the authorization failure. Add these to your question